# Angular 2 easy pie chart not working

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to convert my existing jquery easy-pie-chart to Angular 2. As I am finding it difficult to completely rewrite entire code, I am trying to modify in bits and pieces.

Now to convert existing code I have done this (earlier it was inner-html but event binding not working in Angular 2) .

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center;" *ngFor="let piedata of piemasterData">
    <label (click)="getData(piedata[1])" > {{piedata[1]}} </label>

    <div class="chart" data-percent= piedata[7] >
        <span class="percent">
            {{piedata[7]}}
        </span>
    </div>
    <br/>

</div>
```

Then I am calling

```
$('.chart').easyPieChart({

})
```

Now the problem is the easy-pie-chart is not taking the value set in `data-percent`. Hence its only showing a dot.

[image] .

For example here ABC should take `10.48` and gauge the same value. Further after inspect elementing I saw the `data-percent="piedata[7]"` . I tried many combinations `{{piedata[7]}}` but still the value is not reflecting. I am not sure how to fix this in Angular 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since i'm in a good mood, here's a directive you can use to display pies :

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as EasyPieChart from '../vendors/easypiechart.min.js'

@Directive({
  selector: 'easy-pie-chart'
})
export class EasyPieChartDirective implements OnInit {

  private pie: any;
  private _percent: number;

  @Input()
  set percent(value) {
    this._percent = value;
    if (this.pie)
      this.pie.update(value);
  };
  get percent() { return this._percent };

  @Input()
  options: any;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pie = new EasyPieChart(this.element.nativeElement, this.options);
    this.pie.update(this.percent)
  }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
<easy-pie-chart [options]="{/*Your options goes here*/}" [percent]="piedata[7]">{{piedata[7]}}</easy-pie-chart>
```

This will also live update the chart if piedata[7] changed.

You will have to add `"allowJs": true` in the compiler options of tsconfig.json to make it work

Answer (score 3):

If you are using easy-pie-chart with ng-2
Here's how your HTML Code should look like ->

```
<div class="pie-chart-item" class="centerthis">
  <div class="chart0" [attr.data-rel]="" data-percent="">
  </div>
<div class="description">
  <div class="description-stats black-text">{{this._percent}}%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And all the work is done in your typescript file

To update the value, make the following changes in your typescript file ->

```
this._percent = value;
jQuery('.chart0').data('easyPieChart').update(this._percent);
```

To dive deeper, A complete working reference can be found on this template. 
Have a look 
https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/ng2-admin/src/app/pages/dashboard/pieChart/pieChart.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can bind non-Angular attribute using this syntax : `[attr.data-percent]="piedata[7]"`

Comment: Yes I have tried that , and now value is showing for `data-percent` . But still the gauge is not working .

Comment: Well, i think your plugin is reading the attribute before angular changed it. Mayby you should use this option of easyPieChart to update the percentage :  `$('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(piedata[7]);`

Comment: why `.data('easyPieChart')` not sure about that

Comment: Also I have multiple `easy-pie-charts`

Comment: `.data('easyPieChart')` give you the instance of the EasyPieChart on the targeted element. The proper way to handle your problem would be to create a directive that instanciate a new EasyPieChart with an Input percent which call the update method on the EasyPieChart object