# how to use interpolation with a data property of a template div in angular (angulary 7)?

Tags: angular, typescript

let's say i have this class property in my component

```
public percentVal: number;

//within the class it got initialized

this.percentVal = parseInt(blahblah);
```

now in my html template i have this "data-percent" property. I already tried

```
data-percent="{{percentVal}}"  OR data-percent={{percentVal}}
```

nothing worked

```
<div class="chart blue" data-percent="{{percentVal}}"
           data-size="40">
      </div>
```

Note: i even console logged the typeof this.percentVal within the component. I was actually passing a correct number type and value

it's somehow like **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182830/angular-2-easy-pie-chart-not-working)** but mine is using angular 7 and not angular 2

I want to see **[image: like this]**

but am currently seeing **[image: This issue]**

Comment: What data-percent should do?

Comment: it's actually going to display the value as is..inside this chart widget plugin..if  i pass an ordinary number it works..but if i do the actual interpolation, it doesn't work at all

Comment: I answered your question, just ensure that there is data there in percentVal.

Comment: I encountered an error using your answer

Comment: please read my question again, I have updated and added a url at the bottom

Comment: I edited my question with pictures

Comment: am using "easy-pie-charts" plugin

Comment: @sasori You should add that to the body of your question then.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that if you want to bind a value to custom template property you need to define it first, for that you can use **directive**.

Then, Use it like this should work

```
<div class="chart blue" [data-percent]="percentVal" data-size="40"></div>
```

Check this 
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data-percent' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Comment: Read the answer again please.

Comment: my problem is similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182830/angular-2-easy-pie-chart-not-working ...but that url is using angular 2...am using angular 7, so am not sure if i need a directive

Comment: I think the answer for the question you mentioned is already using directive, this is my thought l, may be our friends can give you another answer, all the best and good luck